# TntComCtrls.hppファイルはどのような機能のコンポーネントですか？

Tags: c++

C++ Builder 10.3でビルドを実施した時に次のようなエラーが出ました。

> [bcc32c 致命的エラー] Main.h(14): 'TntComCtrls.hpp' file not found

このTntComCtrls.hppというヘッダファイルをエクスプローラーでCドライブ全体を検索をかけてみたのですが、全く引っ掛かりませんでした。
このTntComCtrls.hppというヘッダファイルはどのような機能のコンポーネントなのでしょうか？
また、入手や購入できるサイトなどはありますでしょうか？
どうぞ、ご教示の程よろしくお願い致します。

Comment: [sword-devel RE: Error compiling Sword with BC++6](http://www.crosswire.org/pipermail/sword-devel/2003-July/019059.html) によるとC++Builder5の一部のようです。元はフリーソフトだったようで、[rofl0r/TntUnicode](https://github.com/rofl0r/TntUnicode), [Tnt Unicode Controls](https://www.yunqa.de/delphi/products/tntunicodecontrols/index) にフリーのDelphi版があります。

Comment: DelphiコンパイラでC++のオブジェクトやヘッダが出力出来るようです。[Output - C/C++](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Rio/en/Output_-_C/C%2B%2B)

Comment: 回答頂きありがとうございます。TntUnicodeControls_2.3.0をダウンロードしてみました。自分のPCで\Delphi\d9のディレクトリにあった”TntUnicodeVcl_D90.bdsproj”というプロジェクトファイルを読み込んでみたのですが、”プロジェクトを読み込むためにパーソナリティ Delphi.Personalityが必要ですが、読み込まれていません。プロジェクトが読み込めません。”というエラーが出てきます。自分のPCにはC++ Builder10.3がインストールされていますが、Delphi10.3もインストール必要でしょうか？

Comment: Delphiコンパイラの機能のようなので、変換するつもりならDelphiのインストールも必要でしょう。

Answer (score 0):

TntUnicodeControls_2.3.0.zip内のCBuilderフォルダ内のTntLibR.bpkを先にコンパイルし、TntLibD.bpkをインストールしたらいけるのでは無いでしょうか？

コンパイルエラーで上手く行かない場合は、新規でパッケージを作成しなおしてファイルを追加していく方が良いかもしれません。

追記
ちなみにTntUniCodeControlsはCBuilder2007/Delphi2009以前の非Unicode対応の環境でUnicode対応する為のコントロールなので10.3では基本的に不要かと思います。

Comment: 回答頂きありがとうございます。TntLibR.bpkというファイルはプロジェクトファイルでしょうか？C++ Builder 10.3でも開くことは可能でしょうか？

Comment: CBuilderのパッケージプロジェクトのファイルなんですが10.3では開けないようですね。 bpkファイルをメモ帳等で開いて見ながら新規にパッケージプロジェクトを作成するしか無さそうです

Comment: \TntUnicodeControls_2.3.0\CBuilder このディレクトリの中で、TntLibD.bpk,TntLibR.bpkの2つのプロジェクトに別れている理由は何かありますでしょうか？

Comment: TntLibDが設計時用パッケージ、TntLibRが実行時用パッケージになっているかと思います。どのバージョンからかは忘れましたがコンポーネントを作る時に実行時用パッケージと設計時用パッケージに分けるように変わりました。CBuilderでDelphiソースの設計時パッケージをコンパイルするときにちょっとおまじないが必要です。 http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Rio/ja/Delphi_%E3%82%BD%E3%83%BC%E3%82%B9%E3%82%92%E5%90%AB%E3%82%93%E3%81%A0_C%2B%2B_%E8%A8%AD%E8%A8%88%E6%99%82%E3%83%91%E3%83%83%E3%82%B1%E3%83%BC%E3%82%B8%E3%82%92%E3%82%B3%E3%83%B3%E3%83%91%E3%82%A4%E3%83%AB%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B

Comment: 回答頂きありがとうございます。
TntLibR1003とTntLibD1003それぞれのパッケージ用プロジェクトを新規に作成して、TntLibRプロジェクトには教えて頂いたオプション設定をして、ダウンロードしてきた\TntUnicodeControls_2.3.0\CBuilderディレクトリ内のTntLibR.cpp、TntLibR.resを追加してとりあえずビルドしてみたところ、ビルド成功で、\Win32\Debugディレクトリ内にTntLibR.objと他2つとstaticobjsというディレクトリが作成されました。

Comment: このビルドで出力されたTntLibR.objやstaticobjsディレクトリなどはどのように使用すればよいのでしょうか？

Comment: TntLibR1003をコンパイル後、TntLibD1003のプロジェクトの右クリックメニューのインストールを実行してコンポーネントが登録されれば成功です。 登録されない場合は、プロジェクトに追加するファイルが足りていないのかと思います。 cppファイルでなくsourceフォルダ内のpasファイルを追加しないと駄目かと思います。

Comment: TntLibRプロジェクトはコンパイルのみでOKなんでしょうか？
現在、”C:\Users\kmaeh\OneDrive\ドキュメント\Embarcadero\Studio”というパスにプロジェクトを作成して、TntUnicodeControls_2.3.0のソースコードは”C:\Users\kmaeh\Downloads\”に置いてあるので、プロジェクト内で、:\Users\kmaeh\Downloads\内から読み込んでいるような状態です。

https://gist.github.com/KenjiMaehara/693f2a0d10bf29f243f9de5d7c026d0e

Comment: ”TntLibR”のプロジェクトでは、ビルド実行で成功していますが、”TntLibD”のプロジェクトではエラーが発生している状態です。

Comment: ”[DCC 致命的エラー] TntComCtrls.pas(27): F2613 ユニット 'TntControls' が見つかりません。”というエラーなのですが、単純にTntControls.pasというソースコードがプロジェクトに追加すればよいということでしょうか？